# Do minimal hyperbolic surfaces exist? What do they look like?

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, curvature

I understand that it is impossible to embed* the entire hyperbolic plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. But, can one create a embedding of part of the hyperbolic plane such that the resulting surface is also minimal?

Basically, do there exist surfaces which have $\kappa_1 + \kappa_2 = 0$, but also $\kappa_1 \kappa_2 = const < 0$? What do they look like?

<sub>*"Embed" may not be the correct term here, but I hope the idea is clear.</sub>

Comment: This may not answer your question, but maybe this link to Hilbert's theorem will be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_theorem_%28differential_geometry%29. I know nothing about this, except for seeing crocheted "models of the hyperbolic plane" with crinkly edges, but this link and the Nash embedding theorem it links to seem to be related to your question. I had always assumed the "crinkled edges" models of the hyperbolic disk in $\mathbb{R}^3$ were at least distance-preserving.

Comment: @EricTressler - My limited understanding of Hilbert's theorem is that those crocheted models would get ever more dense at the edges, until at some point the surface would no longer be twice differentiable. What I think I'm asking essentially, is if any of those models are also minimal surfaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$There is no minimal surface of constant negative Gaussian curvature in $\Reals^{3}$, even locally.

Up to scaling, the principal curvatures would satisfy
$$
\kappa_{2} = -\kappa_{1},\qquad
-1 = \kappa_{1} \kappa_{2} = -\kappa_{1}^{2},
$$
so the principal curvatures would be constant: $\kappa_{1} = 1 = -\kappa_{2}$ without loss of generality.

If a surface in $\Reals^{3}$ has constant principal curvatures, the Codazzi equations give $\kappa_{1} - \kappa_{2} = 0$ or $\kappa_{1}\kappa_{2} = 0$. (See, for example, O'Neill, *Elementary Differential Geometry*, Second revised edition, Theorem 2.6, page 272.) This excludes a minimal surface of constant negative Gaussian curvature.

In case it's of interest, a connected surface in $\Reals^{3}$ having constant principal curvatures is part of a plane, cylinder, or sphere. See, for example, O'Neill, *Elementary Differential Geometry*, Second revised edition, Exercise 5 on page 280.

Comment: Does that mean minimal surfaces cannot be tiled by regular heptagons?

Comment: Worse: It means there _are_ no minimal regular heptagons in $\Reals^{3}$ (if "heptagon" refers to a hyperbolic polygon).

Comment: When asymptotic lines cut orthogonally, all surfaces of constant negative Gauss curvature surfaces possess zero average curvature lines locally, following  Euler relation Is n't that correct?

Comment: If $M$ has constant negative curvature and the asymptotic lines are orthogonal at some point $p$ (so the mean curvature of $M$ vanishes at $p$), I'd believe there exists a curve through $p$ along which the mean curvature vanishes (merely for reasons of continuity). In that sense, yes. But in any case, the mean curvature of $M$ does not vanish identically in an open neighborhood of $p$, so $M$ is not minimal near $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Individual saddle points, lines or rings can occur *only locally*, but it cannot occur for entire surfaces due to scalar curvature requirement:

$$ H=0, \kappa_{2} = -\kappa_{1} =1/a ; \, K= \kappa_{1} \kappa_{2} = -1/a^2 $$

To find where they occur let $$ \kappa_{2} = -\kappa_{1}= \tan \psi/a ; \, \kappa_n = 0 \, @ \psi= \pi/4 $$

The necessary condition is therefore that asymptotic lines cut orthogonally.

For example [here](http://virtualmathmuseum.org/Surface/pseudosphere/pseudosphere.html), at  $ \phi= 3 \pi/2 $ a slope line ring for Beltrami pseudosphere, \phi=0 for hyper_pseudospheres.

We may say that is *locally valid* :

1. Every minimal surface when sufficiently extended can contain  a line of constant $K=-1, $ and,
2. Every K<0 surface has a line of H =0.  $